# Exposing a module's data to Views2 using its API

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm forking the [filefield_stats](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_stats) module to provide it with the ability of exposing data into the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module via the [API](http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/index.html).
The filefield_stats schema is as follow:

```
function filefield_stats_schema() {
  $schema['filefield_stats'] = array(
    'fields' => array(      
      'fid'       => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, 'description' => 'Primary Key: the {files}.fid'),
      'vid'       => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, 'description' => 'Primary Key: the {node}.vid'),      
      'uid'       => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, 'description' => 'The {users}.uid of the downloader'),
      'timestamp' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE, 'description' => 'The timestamp of the download'),
      'hostname'  => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 128, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '', 'description' => 'The hostname downloading the file (usually IP)'),
      'referer'   => array('type' => 'text', 'not null' => FALSE, 'description' => 'Referer for the download'),   
    ),
    'indexes' => array('fid_vid' => array('fid', 'vid')),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

Well, so I implemented the **hook_views_api()** in *filefield_stats.module* & added a *filefield_stats.views.inc* file in the module's root directory, here it is:

```
// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 * Provide the ability of exposing data to Views2, for filefield_stats module.
 */

function filefield_stats_views_data() {
    $data = array();
    $data['filefield_stats']['table']['group'] = t('FilefieldStats');

    // Referencing the {node_revisions} table.
    $data['filefield_stats']['table']['join'] = array(
        'node_revisions' => array(
            'left_field' => 'vid',
            'field' => 'vid',
        ),
        'files' => array(
            'left_field' => 'fid',
            'field' => 'fid',
        ),
        'users' => array(
            'left_field' => 'uid',
            'field' => 'uid',
        ),
    );

    // Introducing filefield_stats table fields to Views2.
    // vid: The node's revision ID which wrapped the downloaded file
    $data['filefield_stats']['vid'] = array(
        'title' => t('Node revision ID'),
        'help' => t('The node\'s revision ID which wrapped the downloaded file'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'node_revisions',
            'field' => 'vid',
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
            'label' => t('Node Revision Reference.'),
        ),
    );

    // uid: The ID of the user who downloaded the file.
    $data['filefield_stats']['uid'] = array(
        'title' => t('User ID'),
        'help' => t('The ID of the user who downloaded the file.'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'users',
            'field' => 'uid',
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
            'label' => t('User Reference.'),
        ),
    );

    // fid: The ID of the downloaded file.
    $data['filefield_stats']['fid'] = array(
        'title' => t('File ID'),
        'help' => t('The ID of the downloaded file.'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'files',
            'field' => 'fid',
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
            'label' => t('File Reference.'),
        ),
    );

    // hostname: The hostname which the file has been downloaded from.
    $data['filefield_stats']['hostname'] = array(
        'title' => t('The Hostname'),
        'help' => t('The hostname which the file has been downloaded from.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
    );

    // referer: The referer address which the file download link has been triggered from.
    $data['filefield_stats']['referer'] = array(
        'title' => t('The Referer'),
        'help' => t('The referer which the file download link has been triggered from.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
    );

    // timestamp: The time of the download.
    $data['filefield_stats']['timestamp'] = array(
        'title' => t('Download Time'),
        'help' => t('The time of the download.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
        ),
    );

    return $data;
} // filefield_stats_views_data()
```

According to the Views2 documentations this should work as a minimum, I think. But it doesn't! Also there is no error of any kind, when I come through the views UI, there's nothing about filefield_stats data. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `field` definitions in the code above and also wrong `hook_views_api()` implementation. A working API implementation example can be found here:  http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/sepehr/1073868.git/tree/refs/heads/master:/modules/sms_panel_views

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is in the function name: `hook_views_data()`, it should be `filefield_stats_views_data()`. 
`hook_views_api()` should also be `filefield_stats_views_api()`.

You always replace hook with your module name when implementing them in your own modules.

Comment: oh no, in the module source, hook namings are correct. typos, when I was writing the question. I'll update the question, thank you.

Comment: oops, sorry then :p . Did you try flushing the cache? Double checking the tables?

Comment: yes, I've flushed that, uninstall/reinstalled the module & still nothing. In fact I'm going to query the filefield_stats table via the Drupal db api, unfortunately I have no more time to struggle with this. thank you again.